# form Input datepicker not submitted / inserted to database using jquery/php because of multiple class

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, forms, datepicker

I'm using HTML, php, angular, jquery and MySQL and one of the inputs in my form cannot be inserted into the database due to multiple classes.

The following code doesn't have any problems:

```
<div id="datebirth-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorDateBirth }">
<label>Date of Birth</label>
<input class="form-control" name="dob" ng-model="formData.datebirth">
<span class="help-block" ng-show="errorDateBirth">{{ errorDateBirth }}</span>
```

But the following code doesn't work:

```
<div id="datebirth-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorDateBirth }">
<label>Date of Birth</label>
<input class="form-control datepicker" name="dob" ng-model="formData.datebirth">
<span class="help-block" ng-show="errorDateBirth">{{ errorDateBirth }}</span>
```

I noticed that when I add both the form-control and datepicker classes the input will not be submitted to the database.

Here's the library for datepicker I'm using: http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/

And here's the library for the form I'm using: https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-the-angularjs-way

I'm still new to using jquery and angularjs and still learning using few examples from the internet.

Any help is appreciated!